# Cursor continues to display - despite it being set to none, and only when over a div. Angular2/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

So I'm having a really strange issue with the cursor. Basically, my menu allows keyboard navigation, so whenever a key is pressed, it will hide the cursor.

This works great (left screenshot) but when I have the mouse immediately over the menu itself, the cursor does not hide, despite the body showing inline style of `cursor: none`.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1sjq.jpg

Here is the code that hides the cursor:

```
onKey(event: KeyboardEvent) { 
    var key = event.keyCode;

    //User hit an arrow key, so we can assume they want to navigate using the arrows.
    //Remove the mouse, until the mouse is moved again.
    if (key == 38 || key == 40 || key == 8 || key == 13)
    {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'none';
        this.mouseHidden = true;
    }

    ...
}
```

Here is the code that returns it:

```
onMouseMove()
{
    if (this.mouseHidden) {
        this.mouseHidden = false;
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    }
}
```

And here is my menu template:

```
<div id="menuContainer" *ngIf="!this.displaySplash" (mousemove)="onMouseMove($event)">
    <div id="menu" class="cl-effect-1">
        <div id="menuHeader">
            <h1>{{gameName}}</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="menuContents" #menuContainer>
            <div id="homeMenu" *ngIf="this.displayHome" #homeMenu>
                <button class="mainmenu-button" id="play-button" (click)="pressedPlay()" (mouseover)="onMouseEnter($event)">Play</button>
                <button class="mainmenu-button" id="music-button" (click)="pressedMusic()" (mouseover)="onMouseEnter($event)">Music</button>
                <button class="mainmenu-button" id="credits-button" (click)="pressedCredits()" (mouseover)="onMouseEnter($event)">Credits</button>
                <button class="mainmenu-button" id="exit-button" (click)="pressedBack()" (mouseover)="onMouseEnter($event)">Exit</button>
            </div>
            <div id="soundMenu" *ngIf="displaySound" #soundMenu>
                <button class="mainmenu-button" id="mute-button" (click)="pressedMute()" (mouseover)="onMouseEnter($event)">Mute</button>
                <button class="mainmenu-button" id="volUp-button" (click)="pressedVolUp()" (mouseover)="onMouseEnter($event)">Volume +</button>
                <button class="mainmenu-button" id="volDown-button" (click)="pressedVolDown()" (mouseover)="onMouseEnter($event)">Volume -</button>
                <button class="mainmenu-button" id="back-button" (click)="pressedBack()" (mouseover)="onMouseEnter($event)">Back</button>
            </div>
            <div id="creditsMenu" *ngIf="displayCredits" #creditsMenu>
                <p class="mainmenu-text">Author: <a href="http://www.kilomikewebsites.com">Kilo Mike Software</a></p>
                <p class="mainmenu-text">License: Open Source</p>
                <p class="mainmenu-text">Music License: Public Domain</p>
                <button class="mainmenu-button"  id="back-button" (click)="pressedBack()" (mouseover)="onMouseEnter($event)">Back</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm not sure what else to include, because I honestly have no idea as to why this is happening.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Cheers.

Edit: Oh, you can view the problem here: https://steamboatt.github.io/gravity/
Source Code: https://github.com/Steamboatt/gravity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be wanting to hide the cursor in your entire website.

I'd like to start by outlining this is regarded, in general, as a poor design decision, in terms of *usability* and *accessibility*. First of all, this can be done entirely with `CSS` and it is the recommended way to go about it. So, first, please remove all scripts related to hiding the cursor as they will most likely interact with the method I'm about to propose, rendering it ineffective.

```
body {
  cursor: none;
}
```

should do the trick, in theory.

But most browsers, exactly for the reasons outlined above, have stronger rules applying to `html` elements designed  for `pointer` interaction, when it comes to the `cursor` property. Namely, for `<button>`s. This is why you will need a  stronger `CSS` rule applying. As in:

```
body *, body button {
  cursor: none !important;
}
```

If you don't want this applying on all your elements, feel free to replace `body` with a more specific selector.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need some CSS:

```
 body.hide-cursor * {
     cursor: none;
 }

 document.body.className = 'hide-cursor';
 //or
 document.body.className = '';
```